# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform LWJGL

Tags: java, dll, lwjgl, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to use LWJGL from an applet, but it seems to be loading 32-bit libraries on my 64-bit machine giving me this error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\mcoln172\lwjgl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`, I looked through the Sys file from LWJGL, and it uses the os.arch value to determine to use the 64-bit or the 32-bit libraries. I printed out my computers os.arch, and it seems that it is, as expected, amd64. It shouldn't even try to load lwjgl.dll at all, but it does, and I cant find out what's wrong. Help?

Comment: Post the code where you load LWJGL libraries (if applicable). You may want to try loading the 64 bit jar explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to look at the LWJGL code to discover that if loading lwjgl64.dll fails, it will try to load the 32 bit version instead. The confusing part is that this failure is silent. You can make it produce a log by activating LWJGL debug mode, with for example:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.util.Debug", "true")
```

Doing that revealed the following error trying to load the 64 bit lib:

> [error] [LWJGL] Failed to load 64 bit library: lwjgl64.dll: Access is
>   denied

If you have the same, a solution seems to be giving proper "execute" permissions to the file ([this post](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4598.0) helped, for me). I'm not sure how to do that in all windows versions, but thankfully I can access my files through linux too, and a simple `chmod +x` worked.